# Trying to return a specified number of characters from a gene sequence in R

Tags: r, string, split, substr

I have a DNA sequence like: `cgtcgctgtttgtcaaagtcg....`

that is possibly 1000+ letters long.

However, I only want to look at letters 5 to 200, for example, and to define this subset of the string as a new object.

I tried looking at the `nchar` function, but haven't found something that would do this.

Comment: Could you first just make a temporary string that's a trimmed from the long one?

Comment: How do I trim it?....sorry for naive question (I am a new user)

Comment: I think you would use substr

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help.  I greatly appreciate it.  The substr function is very useful for me.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
substr("cgtcgctgtttgtcaa[...]", 5, 200)
```

See [substr()](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=rdoc:base:substr).

Comment: That link for substr documentation appears to be dead.  How about this one: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/substr.html

Answer (score 6):

Use the substring function:

```
> tmp.string <- paste(LETTERS, collapse="")
> tmp.string <- substr(tmp.string, 4, 10)
> tmp.string
[1] "DEFGHIJ"
```

Answer (score 3):

See also the Bioconductor package [Biostrings](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) that is a good choice if you need to handle large biological sequences or set of sequences.

```
#source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R");biocLite("Biostrings") 
library(Biostrings)
s <-paste(rep("gtcgctgtttgtcaac",20),collapse="")
d <- DNAString(s)
d[5:200]
as.character(d[5:200])
```